# Given two point coordinates calculate rectangle coordinates android

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have my coordinates from database as

```
 (x,y) ->   (37.18312184219552, -122.5216064453125), (37.74655686277364, -122.63720703125).
```

I need to find the equivalent rectangle bounds to pass to this function.

```
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(0, 0), new LatLng(0, 5), new LatLng(3, 5), new LatLng(0, 0))
        .strokeColor(Color.RED)
        .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Required Result:

[image]

When I do this, it shows two lines and not rectangle.

```
points.add(new LatLong(x,y)); <-- x and y passed from given coordinates
googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                                .addAll(points)
                                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                                .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

Obtained Result:

[image]

JS has a function to calculate the rectangle bounds but Google Maps Android API doesn't seem to have any function or method. Can anyone please help me figure this out.

Comment: Can you post a picture showing what you have and what you want to get?

Comment: Just a guess, but shouldn't the last coordinate be: (3, 0)

Comment: Please see the edited question above @muminers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps because you only added 2 points to the polygon?  If so, then the 2 points mark the diagonal of the desired rectangle - you need the other 2 corners of the rectangle.  Here's code that will create the missing 2 points of the rectangle and draw the rectangle:

```
public static Polygon drawRectangle(Context context,
                                    GoogleMap googleMap,
                                    LatLng latLng1,
                                    LatLng latLng2,
                                    int strokeWidth,
                                    int strokeColor,
                                    int fillColor) {
    Polygon polygon = null;

    if (context != null && googleMap != null && latLng1 != null && latLng2 != null) {
        // create the other 2 points of the rectangle
        LatLng latLng3 = new LatLng(latLng1.latitude, latLng2.longitude);
        LatLng latLng4 = new LatLng(latLng2.latitude, latLng1.longitude);

        googleMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                .add(latLng1)
                .add(latLng3)
                .add(latLng2)
                .add(latLng4)
                .strokeWidth(strokeWidth)
                .strokeColor(strokeColor)
                .fillColor(fillColor));
    }

    return polygon;
}
```

You call it like this:

```
    Polygon polygon = drawRectangle(context,googleMap,
            latLng,marker.getPosition(),
            8,Color.BLACK,Color.parseColor("#44444444"));
```

Comment: Perfect solution..!